# why is or not working for me in python?

Tags: python-3.x

this is my code:

```
for count in range(NOI):
        ig=input("enter a GTIN code: ")
        while ig!=("21356797"):
                print("incorrect")
                ig=input("enter a GTIN code: ")
                count =count+1
```

and this is the output:

```
21356797

13246785

31325974

45689413

34512340

56756777

how many items do you want to buy?: 1
enter a GTIN code: 21356797
>>>
```

which is what i want. However once i put in OR in my while loop, i can't get it to work like the first part:

```
while ig!=("21356797" or "13246785"):
            print("incorrect")
            ig=input("enter a GTIN code: ")
            count =count+1
```

and this is the output:

```
how many items do you want to buy?: 1
enter a GTIN code: 13246785
incorrect
enter a GTIN code: 21356797
>>>
```

Comment: Maybe `while ig!=("21356797" or "13246785"):` => `while not ig in ["21356797", "13246785"]:` Using `or` between 2 strings doesn't really make sense since strings are not Boolean values (although they can be coerced to such, which isn't really what you want).

Comment: `"21356797" or "13246785"` is "21356797", look up the or operator in python. You have to do `ig != ... or ig != ...`

Comment: @Jasper: You need to `and` the conditions together, not `or` them, if you're using `!=`. Otherwise, nothing ever passes, since it will be unequal to one of the values all the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test:

```
ig!=("21356797" or "13246785")
```

evaluates the `or` condition first, returning the first "truthy" value. As such, it's exactly equivalent to:

```
ig!= "21356797"
```

since `"21356797"` is truthy.

You want a containment test:

```
ig not in ("21356797", "13246785")
```

or two sequential `!=` tests and-ed together:

```
ig != "21356797" and ig != "13246785"
# Equivalent to:
not (ig == "21356797" or ig == "13246785")
```

The containment test scales to a larger set of values more cleanly, and as long as all the values are string literals, will be equally efficient (CPython caches the constant `tuple` of literals).